# Loading different JS file for iPad only?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load a different Javascript file if the site is viewed on ipad.

I have the following code but it puts the code in head section (`between head tags`) because of this line of code:

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
```

I was just wondering how I can place the code where ever I want i.e. between a div without name or at the bottom of the page instead of placing automatically in between the `head tags`?

```
  <script language="javascript">

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null){ // may need changing?
  var js = document.createElement('script');
  js.type = "text/javascript";
  js.src = "mainaPPiPad.js";

  var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  h.appendChild(js);
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ...just append it to a different element. The easiest way would be to give a div an ID, get that div, append said script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line to point at another element in the document:

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
```

To append it to the end of `<body>`, you'd do:

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

Or to append it to `<div id="foobar">`:

```
var h = document.getElementById('foobar');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just select the element via JavaScript and append it. For example:

```
<div id="magic-div"></div>

document.getElementById('magic-div').appendChild(myNode);
```